# i'm learning the LLM in chainlit to create simple chatgpt. and i got this error message

Tags: python

ERROR:    [Errno 10048] error while attempting to bind on address ('0.0.0.0', 8000): only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. help me please ?

I tried to run this code :

```
`import chainlit as cl
 import os
 import openai

 os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = 'xxx'
 #openai.api_key = 'xxx'
 #return everything that the user inputs.
 #pass the message into chatgpt api, .send() the answer.
 @cl.on_message
 async def main (message : str):
     response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
         model = 'gpt-4',
         message = [
             {"role":"assistant" ,"content": "You are a helpful assistant"},
             {"role":"user","content": message}
         ],
         temperature = 1,
     )
     await cl.Message(content = str (response['choices'][0]['message']['content'])).send(`)
`

but i got this output :
[chainlit display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL9sx.jpg)
```

any kind of help would be appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the port?

Maybe could solve it

```
chainlit run app.py --port 8001
```